# Replacing Punctuation With Double Exclamation

Tags: java

My purpose is to replace every . and ! with !! when the user enters a text.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter a text: ");
        String theText = input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("The modified text would be: ");
        System.out.println(replace(theText));
}

public static String replace(String text)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
        {
            if (text.substring(i,i+1).equals(".") || text.substring(i,i+1).equals("!"))
        {
            String front = text.substring(0,i);
                String back = text.substring(i+1);
                text = front + "!!" + back;
        }
        }
    return text;
}
```

For example, when the user enters "Hello. I am using Java!" , it should return "Hello! I am using Java!!"

The problem is that it returns nothing. What is the error?
P.S. I must use the for loop in the program.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips about how to debug your code.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you are changing the string that you are looping over. This causes your substring calculations to be incorrect. Instead, I recommend building a new string.

Comment: the problem is that you are replacing `!` by `!!` and then the next iteration will do the same with the second `!` just inserted in previous   iteration, that is, the second just inserted `!` is also replaced by `!!` and the whole is repeated over and over - a never-ending loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over each character in the `String` (use `charAt`, not `substring` to get one character at a specific index), and add the new characters into a `StringBuilder` to store the result. It is best not to modify what you are iterating over.

```java
public static String replace(String text) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
        if (text.charAt(i) == '.' || text.charAt(i) == '!') sb.append("!!");
        else sb.append(text.charAt(i));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Alternatively, use `String#replaceAll` with a regular expression.

```java
return text.replaceAll("[.!]", "!!");
```